# Python - Error when correct answer is inputted

Tags: python

When I choose question 3, even I do put in the right answer(value_c * value_d, it tells me that it is incorrect. Help?

```
import random

value_a = random.randint(100, 999)
value_b = random.randint(100, 999)
value_c = random.randint(21, 89)
value_d = random.randint(21, 89)
value_e = random.randint(81, 100)
value_f = random.randint(81, 100)

print('''Straight to the point. Pick an option.
1. 2 numbers with 3-digit values added.")
2. 2 numbers with 3-digit values added and then multiplied by 2.
3. 2 numbers with 2-digit values and less than 89 multiplied.
4. 2 numbers with 2-digit values and between 80 and 100 multiplied.
5. 3 random numbers added or subtracted.''')

question = int(input("Choose the type of question you want: "))
print("\n")

if question == 1:
    answer = int(input(str(value_a) + " + " + str(value_b) + " : "))
    if answer == value_a + value_b:
        print("Dayum quicc mafs, trie again if yu wand.")
    else:
        print("Bed mafs.")

elif question == 2:
    answer = int(input( "(" + str(value_a) + "+" + str(value_b) + ")"+ "*2" + " : "))
    if answer == 2*(value_a + value_b):
        print("Dayum quicc mafs.")
    else:
        print("Bed mafs, trie again.")
```

this is the part where my answer never seems to be right:

```
elif question == 3:
    answer == int(input(str(value_c) + " * " + str(value_d) + " : "))
    print(value_c, value_d)
    if answer == value_c * value_d:
        print("Dayum quicc mafs.")
    else:
        print("Bed mafs, trie again.")
```

Comment: `answer == int(...)` is not assigning to `answer`. You mean `answer = int(...)` (single equals sign)

Comment: not answering your question, but for good practice I'd recommend checking if your input is an int before converting it to one, because if it isn't, you program will crash. (you can never trust users.)

Comment: @Tilman no idea if this pings you as I'm on a mobile, but the pythonic way would be to wrap it in a try/except. Ask for forgiveness rather than permission

Comment: yes, you did the ping right ;) but you're right, that'd not only be more pythonic but also simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, a single `=` means assignment. You used a double `==` which is an equality operator. Don't confuse the two, since the answer is not being assigned. Below I have changed the `==` to `=`.

```
elif question == 3:
    answer = int(input(str(value_c) + " * " + str(value_d) + " : "))
    print(value_c, value_d)
    if answer == (value_c * value_d):
        print("Dayum quicc mafs.")
    else:
        print("Bed mafs, trie again.")
```